# C# Custom Launcher?

Tags: c#, forms, window

I've created a Launcher for my game and at the moment I'm very happy with it. Though it looks like a standard windows form, I've heard you can but through Google Searches found nothing. But is it possible to completely customize the windows form? E.g. like a WoW/Diablo Launcher?

If so are there any places to check out some tutorials or get started?

Comment: changing look on winforms the only 3 method i know are : 1- make every single control a custom user control, 2 -Play around with `on_paint` of every single control, 3 - or make the interface in a drawing software such as Gimp/Photoshop,Paint.net and use picture box and mouseover events and such. But easiest of all is to switch to WPF. as example the Diablo 3 laucher is VERY easily replicable in WPF in a day for someone that know WPF well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using visual studio, there are many options regarding window styles and customizability. For example for my game launcher I simply turned off all of the windows boarders. I followed a video similar to https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PiTnIc50tAA to get the basic game launcher then I customised it by turning off the property "Control Box" and setting minimize and maximize properties to false. I was able to achieve a custom game window. I hope this helps !